# Rails 4 Heroku does not show images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've searched through Stack lot of times but still nothing works for me.
Images Ive set in my css.erb file does not show in heroku app.
here is my css file example

```
 .bird-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  background: url(<%= image_path 'bird-bg.jpg' %>);
  background-size: auto 600px;
  background-position: top center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden; }
```

I've changed producion.rb

```
  config.serve_static_files = true;#ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?  
  config.assets.compile = true
```

But that did not help at all.
Also I tried to compile locally than push to heroku, still no result. Can anybody tell me the way out?

Comment: Can you inspect the page load and check if the image is actually loading?  Also try setting adding display:block; and width:X to the element.

Comment: Have you tried `background: image-url('bird-bg.jpg');`?

Comment: Did you make sure you have the rails 12 factor gem installed?

Comment: background: image-url('bird-bg.jpg'); actually its for scss(am I wrong?). I do have tons of plain css .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to development console in your browser and check if images are loaded
2. Try to precompile assets on heroku using `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Comment: nothing happend. No it is not loaded in browser. hroku logs give errors on loading images

Comment: it is bad idea to use css.erb. try to use img-url helper for such a purpose

Comment: it is bad idea to use css.erb Why? Actually it helped, now its Ok I've changed to background: url(<%= image_path 'module-bg.jpg' %>); and also renamed application.css to css.erb

Comment: avoid using css.erb as well as js.erb. this is old way of doing things. if you want some kind of logic in your css try to use scss/sass/less, also avoid writing your styles directly in application.css, create separate file for scope, it is easier to manipulate with styles is such a way. For example: header.css, content.css, footer.css